# Linux Driver CH341 USB Adapter Serial Port issue

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, serial

On a x86_64 miniPC, a led strip can be controlled sending some bytes on a serial port.
This control works on Windows but fails on Linux.

On Windows, these lines in PowerShell switch the led strip off:

```
$port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM3, 9600, None, 8, one
$port.Open()
$bytes = [byte[]] (0xfa, 0x04, 0x03, 0x03, 0x04)
$port.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)
$port.Close()
```

On Linux, these lines should do the same (root user):

```
SERIAL_PORT="/dev/ttyUSB0"
stty -F $SERIAL_PORT cs8 -cstopb -parenb 9600
printf "\xfa\x04\x03\x03\x04" > $SERIAL_PORT
```

but the led strip remains on.

I have also compiled a basic Qt5 application with QSerialPort: same source code for Windows and Linux. The result is the same, i.e. Windows application provides the good result, the Linux one has no effect.

So I suspect the Linux driver CH341.

Here come some kernel logs:

```
3.587111] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
3.587120] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
3.589539] usbcore: registered new interface driver ch341
3.589549] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for ch341-uart
3.589564] ch341 1-7:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
3.612837] usb 1-7: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

On Windows, the driver is CH340 version 1.3.0

I have read [this StackOverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040820/driver-ch341-usb-adapter-serial-port-or-qserialport-not-works-in-linux) but it was written 9 years ago. It spoke about some unimplemented ch341 features.

In the vanilla kernel, the driver now implements those features:
[Vanilla Kernel Driver ch341](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/master/drivers/usb/serial/ch341.c)

cf. function ch341_set_termios

The older driver release written by Nanjing QinHeng Electronics handles stop bit and parity.

[Manufacturer wch.cn driver CH34x](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gorgiaxx/CH34x-Driver-Linux/master/ch34x.c)

I have also compiled this [patched driver](https://github.com/juliagoda/CH341SER) with no more success although the module is installed and /dev/ttyUSB0 exposed.

```
lsmod | grep ch34x
ch34x                  24576  0
usbserial              69632  1 ch34x
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with that hardware/driver. But I have often wondered why digital signage seems to lean towards Windows. Aside from using Windows with no license. Maybe it's the success rate of working with odd hardware. I think a USB serial adapter is less expensive than a latte.